# Spring XD - properties file

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-xd

I am creating a custom SpringXD processor. I am trying to read some properties from the SpringXD stream definition and some of them from a properties file. I have the following in my module's XML:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:config/myModule.properties" ignore-resource-not-found="true" system-properties-mode="OVERRIDE" />

<int:channel id="input"/>

<bean id="sessionProperties" class="com.mycompany.namespace.SomeConfigClassName">
    <property name="hostNames" value="${hostNames}"/>
    <property name="port" value="${port}"/>
</bean>

<int:transformer input-channel="input" output-channel="output">
    <bean id="jmsTemplate" class="com.mycompany.namespace.ModuleClassName">
        <property name="sessionProperties" ref="sessionProperties"/>
    </bean>
</int:transformer>

<int:channel id="output"/>
```

And I am defining my stream, like so:

```
stream create --name my-stream --definition "time | my-custom-module --port=1440 | log" --deploy
```

And I keep getting the following error:

```
Command failed org.springframework.xd.rest.client.impl.SpringXDException: Error with option(s) for module my-custom-module of type processor:
    port: option named 'port' is not supported
```

This is the content of my properties file:

```
hostNames=foo.mycompany.com
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to the issue. I had the properties file in the same path as the module's XML file. Spring was picking up the properties file for some reason and was ignoring the XML file. Moving the properties file to a different folder fixed the issue.

Answer (score -1):

Try specifying the property file by entering this when you deploy the stream:

```
--propertiesFile myprops.properties
```